# Localize Validation Messages from XDocument.Validate() in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net

How can the message returned by XDocument.Validate() be localized in .NET 6?

Comment: Usually all messages in .Net come localized (matching current UI culture). Could you please show [mre] that demonstrates the problem you have with that call? Make sure to include setting UI culture to match your one (as it is very likely other SO users will have it set differently).

Comment: There is no UI, it is a Web API.

Comment: So... how it relates to "current UI culture" (you've obviously checked what that means - https://www.bing.com/search?q=current+UI+culture)? Not really sure how your comment relates to request to provide that information as part of the question.